# How to enable xhost access from second user when display:0 is on first user?

Tags: x11, users, display, xhost

Here is my situation:

I have two (sudo) users on a machine:

1. `userA` (created first on the machine. This is also where display `:0` is attached)
2. `userB` (created later)

Being on `userA` I do:

```bsh
export DISPLAY=:0.0
xclock
```

And the clock opens on `DISPLAY:0` as intended.

Now, I want the same steps to work on `userB`. But unfortunately, it shows:

```bsh
No protocol specified
xhost:  unable to open display ":0.0"
```

What I tried:

1. Creating a trusted xauth key using: `xauth generate :0.0 . trusted` which again shows `unable to open display ":0.0"`
2. Copying the `/home/userA/.Xauthority` to `/home/userB/.Xauthority`. (Note: I did not see any key pertaining to display :0 in the `userA` xauth list, even though it works.)
3. Creating trusted xauth key for `:0` on `userA` and copying that key to `userB`.

None of these worked.

**What worked:**

1. I log-in to `userA`. I `export DISPLAY=:0.0` and then `xhost +` to enable access from all clients.
2. I log back in to `userB`. I `export DISPLAY=:0.0` and then `xclock`.

I want to eliminate Step 1. I do NOT want to log-in to `userA` each time. And I did try to `xhost +` from `userB`, which shows error already shown above.

How can I run `xhost +` from `userB`, while also making it think it has the `DISPLAY:0` access?

**Edit**: As mentioned by @user414777, I was able to:

```bsh
# On userA
$ xhost +si:localuser:userB

# On userB
$ export DISPLAY=:0.0 ; xclock
```

And make it work. But these changes don't stay post-reboot.

```bsh
# After rebooting, on userB
$ export DISPLAY=:0.0 ; xclock
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyError: Can't open display: :0.0
```

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, 4.18.0-15-generic

**SOLVED**

I eventually went with a slightly insecure and modified suggestion by @user414777. Instead of adding the change in `~/.xsession` or `Xsession.d`, I added that line in `/etc/profile`, which applies the change for all users.

Answer (score 0):

On most "modern" Linux systems, you can do just:

```
xhost +si:localuser:userB
```

running as `userA` (the one who already has access to the display), then `userB` will be able to connect (if she sets the correct `DISPLAY` environment variable or uses the correct `-display` or `--display` command line options).

That's quite insecure, but (at least on Debian) it's the only thing supported by `Xwayland`, and they're already [forcing it](https://salsa.debian.org/xorg-team/xorg/-/commit/9b1d91483680a3e9282bffb0aca4a08bd533e36e) even with the regular `Xorg`.

---

The regular way, already mentioned in the `xauth(1)` manpage, and in many answers here and elsewhere, is:

```
xauth extract - "$DISPLAY" | ssh userB@localhost xauth merge -
```

but on my system, that only works with `Xorg`, not with `Xwayland`. With the command above, you can use `su` or `sudo` instead of `ssh`, or you can do it in two steps, etc.

Comment: This is what I get:
`localuser:userB being added to access control list
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  109 (X_ChangeHosts)
  Value in failed request:  0xe
  Serial number of failed request:  7
  Current serial number in output stream:  9`

Comment: Have you run the `xhost +si:localuser:userB` as `userA`? If that still doesn't work, try removing/moving away any `~/.Xauthority` from `userB`'s home directory, then try again, and also with the old `xauth extract ... | xauth merge` method.

Comment: If you don't want to log in as `userA` to run those commands, you can put them in some initialization script (e.g. `~/.xsession`, assuming that your system sources it).

Comment: Yes, I ran that command from `userA` and got the error. I also tried removing old .Xauth extracting and merge keys from `userA` to `userB`, which executes, but I still get same error: `Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyError: Can't open display: :0.0` on running `xclock` on `userB`

Comment: The only thing that comes to my mind is that `userA`s `DISPLAY` is not `:0` when you're running those commands. Also, add more info (edit it in your question) about your exact system, distro, etc.

Comment: When I reboot, I have to `xhost -si:localuser:userB` and again `xhost +si:localuser:userB`, which then allows `userB` to open GUI apps on display without error. How can I make this change applicable permanently?

Comment: As I already said, you can put in some X11 session init file, eg. in the `~/.xsession` of `userA`. Or in some per-system file in `/etc/X11/Xsession.d` (though that may be dangerous).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113901/discussion-between-karan-shah-and-user414777).

Comment: Please add your `~/.xsession` (or my `/etc/profile`) solution in your answer so that I can mark it as solved.